# Web8 | Error in Translation Manager | SDL Language cloud

Tags: web8, translation-manager

In my web8 machine I am using SDL Language cloud as a TMS. I have registered and generated the API key [Here](https://cxc-languagecloud.sdl.com)

When I try to put the API key in the translation source configuration I see this error - Unable to load translation management system configuration options. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
[image]
I don't see any error in TranslationManager logs. I am also putting my public/Private IP in the allowed IP at the time of generating Key.

Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been resolved by generating the API key in sandbox mode. Sandbox mode allows the integration without having the commercial account with SDL Language Cloud.